# Crear un Objeto recorriendo valores con el metodo map Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un array:

```
array = ['¿Esta Bien?','¿Estas mal?','¿algo?'];
```

Objeto original:

```
const body = {
  parametres:{},
  questions:{}
}
```

Necesito conseguir:

```
const body = {
  parameters:{},
    questions:{
      question1: ¿Esta Bien?,
      question2: ¿Estas mal?,
      question3: ¿Algo?
     }
}
```

Estoy intentando recorrer mi array con el metodo .map() de la siquiente manera:

```
array.map((a) => body.questions={question:a});

console.log(body);
```

Pero al hacer el console.log recibo lo siguiente:

```
{ 
 parameters: {}, 
 questions: { 
    question: '¿Algo?' } 
 };
```

Solo logro conseguir la ultima pregunta.

¿que metodo podría utlizar para encontrar el objeto questions con las tres preguntas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo resolví así:

```
array = ['¿Esta Bien?','¿Estas mal?','¿algo?'];
body = {
    parameters: {},
    questions: {}
};
array.forEach((el, i) => body.questions[`question${i}`] = el);
```

Lo que genera como resultado:

```sh
{
  parameters: {},
  questions: {
    question0: "¿Esta Bien?",
    question1: "¿Estas mal?",
    question2: "¿algo?"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = ['pregunta1','pregunta2','pregunta3'];

const body = {
  parametres:{},
  questions:{}
}

array.forEach(question => {
    body.questions[question] = question
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(body, null, 2));
```

En el ejemplo lo que se hace es solo iterar el arreglo de preguntas y asignar ese valor como una propiedad en el objeto `questions` y como valor se le asigna la misma pregunta.